# RLC Bandpass Filter network

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, oscillators, electronics, signal-processing

Can anybody tell me what the "s" in this equation is? I am looking for the transfer function of this circuit[image: RLC Bandpass]

[image]

Comment: Have you learned the Laplace transform? 's' is the usual variable in Laplace transform space. Possibly you could think of it as a complex frequency.

Answer (score 1):

The meaning: with $\omega_0=2\pi f_0$ write your equation as $(s^2+2\zeta\omega_0s +\omega_o^2)v_o=(2\zeta\omega_0 s)v_i$ and then substitute $s=\frac{d}{dt}$ that is 
$$\frac{d^2 v_o}{dt^2} +2\zeta\omega_0 \frac{dv_o}{dt} +\omega_o^2v_o = 2\zeta\omega_0 \frac{dv_i}{dt}.$$ The "transfer function" is by definition the rational function $$H(s) = \frac{2\zeta\omega_0 s}{s^2+2\zeta\omega_0s +\omega_o^2}$$ as a function of the *complex* variable $s=\sigma+\mathfrak{j}\omega$

Comment: Thank you for the answer! What is σ in this case? Given a real frequency, can we just set it to 0 and insert the frequency as ω=2πf?

Comment: $\Re[s]=\sigma, \Im[s]=\omega$; yes, you can do that and it will give you $H(\mathfrak{j} \omega)$